# If I change my worldspawn will my spawn chunks move?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm a completely Vanilla Minecrafter, so I don't use 3rd party tools to figure this out.  Finding the spawn chunks takes so long to find the old fashioned way, so can I just move the spawn chunks by changing the location of my world spawn?

Bonus question:  If I find the original Spawn Chunks and set my worldspawn back there, will it revert back to normal and be able to update redstone from anyware on the map?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the spawn chucks will 'move' to the new world spawn point.
However: "Although spawn chunks are usually kept loaded at all times, new spawn chunks won't be loaded by this command until a player moves within range. Compasses (which in Minecraft point to the world spawn rather than north) will also not update to the change until the world is reloaded."

Source: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#setworldspawn

Basically make sure to travel to the new location, and reboot the game for good measure.

Comment: The safe way would be to use `/tp <x> <y> <z>` and `/setworldspawn`, rather than `/setworldspawn <x> <y> <z>`.